# Calling function without parameter, when default parameter is allready defined

Tags: c++, default-value, optional-parameters

It has been a long time since I wrote in C++, and I can't really find a solution to my problem to my question online, hence this question:

I have a class where I want to define a function with a default parameter :Run(par="default")

class.h contains:

```
class Test { public : void Run(QString par="default");};
```

class.cpp contains:

```
void Test::Run(QString par="default") { ... };
```

The issue I get is that when i try to call this function, with no paramater (I want to use the default value), the compiler complains about the nonexistance of a function run().

```
Test test;
test.Run()
```

> 7: error: undefined reference to `Test::Run()'

I would prefere not to use function overloading.

I tried to remove the default value only in the .cpp, but the compiler error remained.

What do I forget here? I am compiling in QT using GCC.

Comment: You should leave the default value only in the declaration, meaning - in the header file.

Comment: Is the error at link time, or at compile time.  Text like "undefined reference" suggests link time, and would be due to the absence of a definition in the compiled program.  Are you compiling and linking in the source file which contains the definition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you declare a default parameter, you only set it within your class declaration. In the definition, you leave it empty.

```
class Test { public : void Run(QString par="default");};
void Test::Run(QString par) { ... };
```

should be fine

Comment: As I said before, I tried to declare the default parameter only in the definition (.h)
The error message remained. This is when i though of something: cleaned the build. Now it works. This reminds my of my strugle in the past with C++. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @Rps sorry, I missread that one, I thought you only set it in the cpp, not the header.